# Связанная таблица в access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Есть база на MS SQL Server, в MS Access создана связанная таблица для таблицы базы.
Внес изменения в базе (изменил названия полей), в Access через диспетчер связанных таблиц обновил связанную таблицу, но структура связанной таблицы не изменилась, следовательно и таблица не открывается.

Какой шаг я мог упустить?

Answer (score 0):

Проверил - все обновляется. Убедитесь, что при открытии диспетчера связанных таблиц выставлена галка напротив требуемой таблицы, по умолчанию отметки сняты. 
Также убедитесь, что после внесения изменений на стороне SQL Server измененная таблица была сохранена и закрыта в редакторе.

Также, возможно, проблема в отключенной опции [Name AutoCorrect](http://allenbrowne.com/bug-03.html). Открываем базу данных (Access 2010) - Файл - параметры - Текущая база данных - Параметры автозамены имен - поставить галки.

Comment: Базу я перезапустил, подключился к ней с другого удаленного места, в базе поля новые, но в Access даже при создании показывает старые поля

Comment: Галки поставлены. Попробовал создать новые связанные таблицы по имеющемуся ODBC, там также старые поля